# error 24 13 android studio faild to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want add a library to my project in Android Studio, but it gave me this error no matter what my library is. I always get this error when I want to add a library:

```
Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0
```

[image]

Do I have to sync the project in online mode to add a library? I sync project online work but sync never be ended.

Comment: *Do I have to sync the project in online mode to add a library?* -- Yes. At least once. Otherwise, how would the library get downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable online mode so gradle can download the JAR and put it into the gradle dependencies directory. Optionally (which I dont recommend) you can download it manually and put it there.

However once you downloaded a particular dependency you gradle will synch it from the local repo, meaning you dont need internet to add it to *another* project.